# Getting started with SIM card

Tags: smartcard, gsm, javacard, sim-card

I want to start working with cell-phones and SIM cards. I searched a lot in the internet but still I have some problem!

I want to know :

**1. What is the difference between (U)SIM cards and Smart Cards?**

As I know, SIM and USIM, both are a kind of smart cards. right? If so, if there any specific hardware difference between regular Smart cards and SIM cards? or all the difference is a specific application (Containing IMSI,KI, so on) on the SIM Cards that there is not available on the regular smart cards?

**2. What is the difference between SIM cards and USIM Cards?**

As you see below (from [here](http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-sim-and-usim-card)), it mentioned that SIM is for 2G and USIM is for 3G, But It said also SIM is 3G compatible, and USIM is backward compatible to 2G! So what is the difference? A single specific application that there is in USIM cards and there is not in SIM cards? or something else?

[image]

**3. Supporting or not supporting 3G or 4G is a feature of the (U)SIM card or is a feature of Telecommunication-System or is a feature of my Cell-phone? or All?**

In the other world, if I have a 2G SIM card, Using 3G protocol needs to changing the SIM card? and also, If I have a SIM for 3G, I neet to change it for using 4G communication? or I just need to install an applet on it?

Or a cellphone that doesn't support 3G or 4G for example, it needs only an application? or It needs a hardware element?

**4. For getting started with smart cards, you recommend me to read *Java card* specifications, *ISO 7816* and *Global Platform Spec*. Now, for (U)SIM cards, what specifications I must search for? What shall I know and learn to developing them?**

And the last one!

**5. Are all the new 3G/4G (U)SIM cards, a kind of Java Cards? (Does they all have JCVM inside?)**

Comment: Your question is too boring, you should break it to have better answers

Comment: I know the answers to 2,3 and 4 off the top of my head, but not 1 or 5 (not sure what you mean by Smart Cards which can be many things or Java Cards).  Please break the question up, five questions is really too many in one!

Comment: @SList , David answered the questions clearly, but may I have your answers to 2,3 and 4 also? just to know more things (maybe) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, both are smart cards. Surely there are some specific applications: the SIM and USIM application theyself, the Remote File Management, Remote Application Management, browser application (S@T, WIB), etc.
2. The SIM card specification is defined first. Later on, the USIM specification. The backward compatibility is required so that subscribers do need need to change their cards (which is also cost for operator). SIM can work only with A0 class, while USIM can work with both A0 and 00.
3. The supports for 2G, 3G, and 4G all requires specific telecommunication system, mobile device, and also the cards. If you are using lower technology , such as 3G in 4G network, you may still able to use the 3G service, but not able to use 4G features.
4. For SIM card, you can refer to [3GPP](http://www.3gpp.org/): TS 11.11, TS 11.14, TS 11.17, TS 23.040, TS 23.048. For USIM, you can refer to [ETSI](http://etsi.org): TS 102.221, TS 102.222, TS 102.223. For CDMA, you can refer to [3GGP2](http://3gpp2.org). There are lots more specifications in those web, I just mentioned some.
5. It can be native or Javacard. But mostly, they will be using Javacards.

Comment: So the main difference between 2G,3G,4G (U)SIM smart cards, is some software that is installed on them? right? I mean, a single specific smartcard (for example JCOPV2.4.2R3) can be a 2G SIM, and also can be a 3G SIM and also can be a 4G USIM if I change its contents (applets)?

Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. However, please note that in the (U)SIM toolkit applications there is send() method to send proactive command. This method puts built proactive command into buffer and skip the JCRE execution, which is more likely require customized javacard. Also, due to execution speed and code size, the (U)SIM APIs are more likely to be implemented in native way.